# Control+Space is not working in Eclipse on Mac

Tags: eclipse, macos

I am using Eclipse on Mac and want to use control+space many times..e.g. if I write sysout and hit control+space..eclipse converts it to System.out.println..but for some reason control+space is not working on my mac..below is a screenshot of whats happening when I hit control+space on sysout

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqtIp.png

Answer (score 0):

I was writing the code outside main..so it was not working..so DUMB of me :'(